# Why isn't a link in my page content clickable?

Tags: html, css

I want to put a link in my main div for potential enterprises to download my CV, but when I try to click on the link, I just can't, It's like the text is not a link at all, even if it is considered as one, probably because something is over it that I just cannot see

For now, even if my web page probably has other problems, I just want to understand why I can't click on this link.

Thanks in advance.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=IBM+Plex+Sans+Thai+Looped:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');

*{
    font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans Thai Looped', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root{
    /* ===== Couleurs ===== */
    --body-color: #E4E9F7;
    --sidebar-color: #FFF;
    --primary-color: #308EC4;
    --primary-color-light: #F6F5FF;
    --toggle-color: #DDD;
    --text-color: #707070;

    /* ===== Transition ===== */
    --tran-02: all 0.2s ease;
    --tran-03: all 0.3s ease;
    --tran-04: all 0.4s ease;
    --tran-05: all 0.5s ease;
}


body{
    height: 100vh;
    background: var(--body-color);
    transition: var(--tran-04);
}

body.dark{
    --body-color: #18191A;
    --sidebar-color: #242526;
    --primary-color: #3A3B3C;
    --primary-color-light: #3A3B3C;
    --toggle-color: #FFF;
    --text-color: #CCC;
}

/** Page web **/

header{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 40px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    background: var(--sidebar-color);
    color: var(--text-color);
    transition: var(--tran-05);
}
/* ===== Sidebar ===== */

.sidebar{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
    background: var(--sidebar-color);
    padding: 10px 14px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: var(--text-color);
    border-style: solid;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: var(--tran-05);
    z-index: 100;
}

.sidebar.close{
    width: 88px;
}

 /* ===== Menu de naviguation ===== */

 .headerNav .menu{
    color: var(--text-color);
    transition: var(--tran-05);
}

.sidebar .text{
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color:var(--text-color);
    transition: var(--tran-03);
    white-space: nowrap;
    opacity: 1;
}

.sidebar .menu-bar{
    margin-top: 35px;
}

.sidebar.close .text{
    opacity: 0;
}

.sidebar.close .headerNav .menu{
    opacity: 0;
}

.sidebar .image{
   min-width: 60px;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}

.image-text img{
    width: 60px;
    border-radius: 6px;
}

 .sidebar .headerNav .image-text{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center; 
}

.sidebar li{
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
 
}

.sidebar li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    transition: var(--tran-04);
}
 
.sidebar li a:hover{
    background: var(--primary-color);
}
 
.sidebar li a:hover .icons,
.sidebar li a:hover .text{
   color: var(--sidebar-color)
}

.sidebar li .icons{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    min-width: 60px;
}


.sidebar li .icons,
.sidebar li .text{
   color: var(--text-color);
   transition: var(--tran-03);
}

.sidebar .nav-lien{
    background: var(--primary-color-light);
    border-radius: 6px;
    transition: var(--tran-05);
}

.sidebar .search-box{
    background: var(--primary-color-light);
    border-radius: 6px;
    transition: var(--tran-05);
}
 
 .search-box input{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: var(--primary-color-light);
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 6px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight:  500;
    transition: var(--tran-05);
}
 
.sidebar button{
    position: fixed;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    bottom: 10px;
}
 
.sidebar .headerNav{
    position: relative;
}
 
.sidebar .headerNav .toggle{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: -25px;
    transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(180deg);
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    background: var(--primary-color);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: var(--sidebar-color);
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: var(--tran-03);
}

.sidebar.close .headerNav .toggle{
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

body.dark .sidebar .headerNav .toggle{
    color: var(--text-color);
}

.sidebar .menu-bar{
    height: calc(100% - 50px);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
 
.menu-bar .mode{
    background: var(--primary-color-light);
    border-radius: 6px;
    position: relative;
    transition: var(--tran-05);
}
.menu-bar .mode i{
    position: absolute;
    transition: var(--tran-03);
}
 
.menu-bar .mode .moon-sun{
    height: 50px;
    width: 60px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
 
.menu-bar .mode i.sun{
    opacity: 0;
}

body.dark .menu-bar .mode i.sun{
    opacity: 1;
}
body.dark .menu-bar .mode i.moon{
    opacity: 0;
}
 
.menu-bar .contenu-bas{
    position: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 260px;
}


.menu-bar .mode .activer-switch{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 60px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background: var(--primary-color-light);
    transition: var(--tran-05);
}
 
.activer-switch .switch{
    position: relative;
    height: 22px;
    width: 44px;
    background: var(--toggle-color);
    border-radius: 25px;
    transition: var(--tran-05);
}
 
.switch::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 5px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    background: var(--sidebar-color);
    transition: var(--tran-03);
    cursor: pointer;
}
 
body.dark .switch::before{
    left: 24px;
 
}

/* ===== Contenu  ===== */

.liste{
    position: sticky;
    top: 120px;
    left: 15%;
    width: 80%;
    height: 2000px;
    background: var(--sidebar-color);
    padding: 10px 14px;
    margin-top: 120px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: var(--text-color);
    border-style: solid;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: var(--tran-05);
    z-index: -10;
    align-items: center;
    color: var(--text-color);
}

#Apropos p{
    position: inherit;
    margin-right: 22%;
}

#Apropos .photo{
    position: absolute ;
    display: block;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 180px;
}

.photo #pdp{
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    height: 170px;
    width: 132px;
}
```

```html
    <head>      <meta charset="utf-8">
        <!-- link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" -->
        <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.1/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
  </head>

  <body>
        <header> Portfolio TOURNEBIZE Kélyan </header>

        <nav class="sidebar close">
            <h3 class="headerNav">
                <div class="image-text">
                    <span class="image">
                        <img src="logo.png" alt="logo">
                    </span>
                    <div>
                        <span class="menu"> Onglets </span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <i class='bx bx-chevron-right toggle'></i>
            </h3>
      
            <ul class="menu-bar"> 
                <li class="nav-lien">
                    <a href="#Apropos">
                        <i class='bx bx-user-circle icons'></i>
                        <span class="text nav-text"> A propos de moi </span>
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-lien">
                    <a href="#Formation">
                        <i class='bx bx-building-house icons'></i>
                        <span class="text nav-text"> Formation </span>
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-lien">
                    <a href="#Experience">
                        <i class='bx bx-briefcase-alt icons' ></i>
                        <span class="text nav-text"> Expériences </span>
                    </a>
                </li>


                <li class="nav-lien"> 
                    <a href="#Competence">
                        <i class='bx bx-slider icons'></i>
                        <span class="text nav-text"> Compétences</span>
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-lien"> 
                    <a href="#Projet">
                        <i class='bx bx-spreadsheet icons'></i>
                        <span class="text nav-text"> Projets</span>
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-lien"> 
                    <a href="#Divers">
                        <i class='bx bx-book-bookmark icons'></i>
                        <span class="text nav-text"> Divers</span>
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-lien"> 
                    <a href="#CV">
                        <i class='bx bx-file icons'></i>
                        <span class="text nav-text"> CV</span>
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-lien"> 
                    <a href="#Contact">
                        <i class='bx bx-envelope icons'></i>
                        <span class="text nav-text"> Contact</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            
            
            
            

                <div class="contenu-bas">
                    <li class="mode">
                        <div class="moon-sun">
                            <i class="bx bx-moon icons moon"></i>
                            <i class="bx bx-sun icons sun"></i>
                        </div>
                        <span class="mode-text text">Mode Sombre</span>

                        <div class="activer-switch">
                            <span class="switch"></span>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <div class="liste">
            <div id="Apropos">
                <h3>A propos de moi</h3>
                    <div class="photo">
                        <img src="photo.jpg" alt="Photo" id="pdp">
                    </div>
                <p> Section "A propos de moi"</p>
            </div>
            <div id="Formation">
                <h3>Formation</h3>
                <p>Section "formation"</p>
            </div>
            <div id="Experience">
                <h3>Experiences Professionnels</h3>
                <p>Section "experience"</p>
            </div>
            <div id="Competence">
                <h3>Compétences</h3>
                <p>Section "compétences"</p>
            </div>
            <div id="Projet">
                <h3>Projets</h3>
                <p>Section "projets"</p>
            </div>
            <div id="Divers">
                <h3>Divers</h3>
                <p>Section "divers"</p>
            </div>
            <div id="CV">
                <h3>CV</h3>
                <p>Section "cv"</p>
                <a href="#Contact">Télécharger mon cv</a>
            </div>
            <div id="Contact">
                <h3>Contact</h3>
                <p>Section "contact"</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- script src="Scripts/main.js"> </script -->
    
    </body>
```

Comment: _"probably because something is over it that I just cannot see"_ - then make a right click in that position, and "inspect element" - and see what you actually land on in the DOM inspector.

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Also take the [tour].

Comment: `z-index: -10;` - Why?